# How to use RandomAccessFile through AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We package few resource files in the package.
Though we can access it through `InputStream` through `getResourceAsStream`, how can we access it as `RandomAccessFile`?
I believe as the file is zipped and may not be feasible to access it as `RandomAccessFile`, is there any alternative to achieve the said functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using below line:

fileName = getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile();

One can access RandomAccessFile using:

RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName,"r");

So if fileName is "/abc.properties" under resources folder, appending above will just work fine.
It basically appends "/var/task/"